# Redis / Memcached ReST caching for an external service

Tags: rest, caching, web, redis, memcached

Question here about caching data from calls to an external ReST API.

There is currently a ReST service set up to generate and retrieve some specific types of reports that the UI must consume. However, this service is not meant for high volume usage, or to be exposed to the public and these reports are fairly static. Possibly only changing every 10-20 minutes. The web application resides on a separate server.

What I would like to do is, using memcached or Redis, is when a request for data comes in from the UI to the web back-end, make a call from the web application back-end to the report server to get the specified report, transform the data to the appropriate format for the UI to consume, cache it with a timestamp, and return it to the UI so subsequent requests will be available in memory on the web applications back-end without having to re-request from the report server. I would also need to check this timestamp and make a new request if the cached report has been held for longer than the specified time. The data that will be cached is fairly minuscule just some smallish JSON objects with only a handful of values holding the information the UI needs and there is NOT a ton of these objects, I would not be surprised if they could all be easily stored in memory at once so the time stamping is the only invalidation that should be necessary.

I have almost 0 experience here when it comes to caching / memcached / Redis. Is there advantages to one or the other? Is something like this possible? How would I go about implementing this? Are there other options?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-caching these kinds of RESTful query responses is very possible and quite common.

With any server based caching, you should also think hard about whether you really need it, as it does [add complexity](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096). It can certainly make a huge improvement, but since your usage volume is low, it might actually be overkill. You may also be able to use HTTP caching protocols to avoid the need for caching on the server. If the data doesn't change very often and you use eTags or modified dates correctly, along with an intermediary proxy like AWS CloudFront, users will rarely experience that delay.

Also, if you are finding your database to be a bottleneck, you might be able to get away with just configuring it to cache more aggressively.

Assuming you do want to cache in memory ...

For server-side caching, the normal approach is to cache results for some time period or manually clear them from the cache. But a more modern and better approach imo is to use [Russian-doll caching](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/russian-doll-caching-cache-digests-rails-4-countdown-to-2013), where you key items according to the time their inputs changed. Then you never need to worry about manually clearing them, you just make sure timestamps are correct and synchronised.

Memcached versus Redis versus something else? For this usage, Memcached is probably best as it's extremely simple and you don't have to worry about persistence, which is a big advantage of Redis over Memcached. Redis is well-engineered and would work fine too, but I don't see the benefit to use something that's considerably more feature-rich and complex if you don't need it and there's a good alternative. That said, the one big advantage of Redis  is it now has excellent built-in clustering support, so it's easy to scale and stay online. But that would be overkill for your use case.

Something else? There are plenty of other in-memory databases, but I think Memcached and Redis are probably best if you want to avoid the problems of relying on cutting-edge frameworks without too much support. However, there *is* something else: boring old files. If you're generating reports, you might want to consider just generating them as temporary files. If your OS is doing its job, the files will end up being cached anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I considered plain files, however I felt Memcached or Redis may be the right choice to simplify things. I was interested in Redis as it's something I probably would like to learn in the future. But seems like Memcached is the way I will go in this case. The server side caching is necessary as the server generating the reports is being developed by a third party, not intended to be public facing and the developer has expressed that they do not want to deal with the volume of requests we will be expecting. Thanks very much for your answer!